# Why are non-explicit constructors hidden by explicit ones when using initializer lists?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider following binary tree, where nodes have two sons or are leafs with labels. This code compiles in g++ 4.7.2:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Tree {
    unique_ptr<Tree> left, right;
    char label;

    Tree(char label) : label(label) {}

    Tree(Tree && left, Tree && right) :
        left(new Tree(move(left))), 
        right(new Tree(move(right))) {}

    //~ explicit Tree(Tree && left, bool right) {}

} tree {{1, 2}, 3};
```

When I uncomment explicit constructor it fails to compile (if this explicit constructor is private it fails too). Is this gcc bug, or explicit constructors forbid using initializer list construction for non-explicit ones with same number of arguments?

Edit: s/implicit/non-explicit/. Sorry for confusion, I used word "implicit" for "allowing implicit conversion" and "explicit" as "marked with the keyword explicit". I call constructors automagically generated by compiler "default", so I didn't notice word "implicit" will be so ambiguous.

Comment: Which "explicit constructor"? I see two. And AFAIR, in the moment you define a constructor the default ones aren't defined by the compiler.

Comment: It should fail to compile whether you use {} or () initialization syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems to assume something which is not true, and reveals a fundamental misunderstanding.

To begin with, implicitly generated constructors are not hidden "when using initializer lists". Their generation is simply inhibited any time you define a constructor, no matter whether you mark it as `explicit` or not.

Beware though: what is usually meant by "implicit" constructor is a constructor which is implicitly (automatically) generated by the compiler when you provide none, not a constructor which lacks the `explicit` modifier. In the above paragraph I was talking about the former, but I am led to believe that you are thinking about the latter.

Assuming that this is the case, it is not true that constructors which are not marked as `explicit` are hidden by ones that are marked as `explicit` *in general*, whether or not you are using initializer lists.

The reason your program does not compile is that your `explicit` constructor happens to be a better match than the non-`explicit` one, because it accepts a `bool` as its second argument, which only requires a standard conversion to match the argument `2`. On the other hand, your non-`explicit` constructor accepting a `Tree&&` requires a user-defined conversion involving the construction of a temporary `Tree` object, and standard conversions are preferable over user-defined conversions.

To force the compiler to construct a `Tree` temporary from the argument `2` rather than converting `2` to a `bool` (and, therefore, invoke the non-`explicit` constructor), you must specify this by changing your constructor invocation into the following:

```
struct Tree
{
    ...
} tree {{1, Tree(2)}, 3}; // Explicitly specify the second argument is to be
                          // used to create a temporary Tree object, rather
                          // than being converted to a bool
```

Also notice, that while the same applies to the creation of the top-level tree (i.e. `3` gets converted into a `bool` as well and your `explicit` constructor is invoked again), this is not a problem in this case, because you are direct-initializing the `tree` object, and no implicit conversion is attempted.

Comment: Your argument about conversions preferability seems reasonable. Is it a standard defined behavior that explicit constructors in such a situation are taken into consideration only to result in a compiler error?

Comment: @krdln: Not sure what you mean, but if you're asking why the compiler doesn't trace back the overload resolution and choose the other constructor once it figures out that the best match leads to troubles, then yes, it is standard behavior. The best match is chosen, and if the resulting call is not legal (e.g. because the constructor is `private`, or `explicit` as in this case), an error is issued.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem might be:

```
template<
  typename Bool,
  typename=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      typename std::decay<Bool>::type,
      bool
    >
  >::type
>
explicit Tree(Tree && left, Bool&& right) {}
```

where I have blocked conversion from any type other than `bool` and variants from being passed as the 2nd argument.

You might, however, be better off creating a static method that does what this constructor wants to do rather than throwing yet more overloaded constructors at the problem.